# XML -> XSL -> Bulleted list with hyperlinks

Tags: xml, xslt

I am truly scratching my head with this one. I would like to create a bulleted list with hyperlinks from an XML excerpt. I can create the bulleted list, but I can't work out how to get the part together.

Here is the XML:

```
<list>
    <listitem>1<hyperlink><url>page1.xml</url><name>Go to Page 1</name></hyperlink></listitem>
    <listitem>2<hyperlink><url>page2.xml</url><name>Go to Page 2</name></hyperlink></listitem>
    <listitem>3<hyperlink><url>page3.xml</url><name>Go to Page 3</name></hyperlink></listitem>
    <listitem>4<hyperlink><url>page4.xml</url><name>Go to Page 4</name></hyperlink></listitem>
</list>
```

...and the XSL so far. The hyperlink components do not work. It may look a bit untidy through my attempts to make it work. I would like the "Go to Page n" to be the hyperlink.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">


<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="list">
    <DIV>
        <UL><xsl:apply-templates /></UL>
    </DIV>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="listitem">
    <DIV>
        <LI><xsl:apply-templates />  </LI>
    </DIV>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="hyperlink">
        <A>
            <xsl:value-of select="hyperlink" />
        </A>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="hyperlink/url">
         HREF='<xsl:value-of select="url" />'  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="hyperlink/name">
         <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

The current result is:

**1. HREF='page1.xml' Go to Page 1

1. HREF='page2.xml' Go to Page 2
2. HREF='page3.xml' Go to Page 3
3. HREF='page4.xml' Go to Page 4
   **

What I need is HTML akin to this:

`<A HREF='page1.xml'>Go to Page 1</A>`

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need take the `DIV` out of the `listitem` template (because the `LI` needs to end up directly inside the `UL`), and you can simplify all the `hyperlink` stuff down to one template

```
<xsl:template match="hyperlink">
  <A href="{url}">
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
  </A>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: And add a catch-all template to defeat the built-in default template: `<xsl:template match="text()|@*"></xsl:template>`

Comment: @Geoff in this case suppressing the default template would stop the 1, 2, 3, 4 getting printed before the `<A>`.  This may or may not be the desired result, it's hard to tell from the question.

Comment: True - I guess it depends if the OP wants an ordered unordered list :-)